# NSFetchRequest returns old data even though the database is updated

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsfetchrequest

I'm working on a Multi-threaded application that uses Coredata.

When i save some data on one thread it goes to the database but when I try to fetch it from a different thread once the data is saved to the database, the fetch request returns the old data.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using same moc for both threads?

Comment: Have you read the Apple docs on concurrency and made sure you're using one of the supported patterns?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1

Comment: boranA- I'm using a MOC per thread.

Comment: David - I did read it. That's why I'm using MOC per thread. Can't figure out why thus us happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue due to the MOC merge policy.
I have used `NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy` earlier and switching to `NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy` fixed the issue. Keep in mind, this should be picked according to your need.