# NSManagedContext returning old data instead new

Tags: ios, database, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

In my app, I have used Double Model of NSManagedContext.
Have one child `managedObjectContext` with `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and parent
`writerManagedObjectContext` with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` which saves data to `PersistentStoreCoordinator`. I am able to save data in database but while retrieving I am getting old values instead new.

Below code is to save context to `parent context` and then to `PersistentStoreCoordinator`.

```
 [managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            //push to parent
            //NSLog(@"pushing to parent context (writer context)");
            NSError * error;
            if([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]){
                NSLog(@"main Save Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

            //NSLog(@"pushing to persistentstore");
            [self.writerManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                //push to parent
                NSError * error;
                if([self.writerManagedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![self.writerManagedObjectContext save:&error]){
                    NSLog(@"writer Save Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
            }];
        }];
```

Found the same [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22456959/1635315) on stack-overflow but its answer isn't helpful for my issue. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: have you checked your db file if it's updated with latest values in any SQLite browser?

Answer (score 0):

Set `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` of the main context to YES.

The writing context is talking directly to the  PersistentStoreCoordinator, so there is no way to the main context to know that there is any change.  The context has a cache and don't always access the database to get the data.  Before iOS 10 you need to monitor the notifications and call `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification`; in iOS 10 `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` was added which makes this a lot easier.